# Create array inside foreach-loop with children from another loop

Tags: php

Based on data from an XML-file stored in the variable `$Xml` I want to create a new array with custom properties.

I did start with a foreach-loop:

```php
foreach($Xml->Sequences->Sequence as $var=>$value) {

    $MyObject[] = array(
        "title"  => $value->SequenceName->__toString(),
        "folder" => true
    );

}
```

That's OK. The result looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Folder1
            [folder] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Folder2
            [folder] => 1
        )
)
```

The variable `$Xml` also contains sub-properties and I need to insert them in my new array.
The desired result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Folder1
            [folder] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Package1
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

I don't know how to get this result!
In my opinion, I need to start another foreach-loop to get the sub-properties and store them in the array for the current element in the loop. I did use a code like this, but ofc a new node is created and it is not stored in the parent-node.

```php
foreach($Xml->Sequences->Sequence as $var=>$value) {

    $MyObject[] = array(
        "title"  => $value->SequenceName->__toString(),
        "folder" => true,
    );

    foreach ($value->SequencePackages->Package as $a=>$b){
        $MyObject[] = array(
            "children" => array(array(
                "title" => $b->PackageFolder->__toString(),
            ))
        );
    }

}
```

I believe the solution is easy, but I can't figure out alone ...

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to build up the new array data and add it into the main array at the end rather than at each stage...

```
$MyObject = [];
foreach($Xml->Sequences->Sequence as $var=>$value) {
    $newObject =array(
        "title"  => $value->SequenceName->__toString(),
        "folder" => true,
    );

    foreach ($value->SequencePackages->Package as $a=>$b){
        $newObject["children"][] = ["title" => $b->PackageFolder->__toString()];
    }
    $MyObject[] = $newObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some thing like this . You need to use the key from the parent array and insert new value children 
foreach($Xml->Sequences->Sequence as $var=>$value) {

```
$MyObject[] = array(
    "title"  => $value->SequenceName->__toString(),
    "folder" => true,
);

foreach ($value->SequencePackages->Package as $a=>$b){
    $MyObject[‘children’] = array(
            "title" => $b->PackageFolder->__toString(),

    );
}

}
```

Comment: I have just tried it. This does not work. The variable $var is always the same and it is not numeric.

Comment: Okay I thought it is numeric. in that case you take a variable outside the loop and increment it at the end of loop

Answer (score 0):

User index of parent loop to create array.

```
$MyObject[$var] = array(
        "title"  => $value->SequenceName->__toString(),
        "folder" => true
    );

$MyObject[$var]['children'][] = array(array(
                "title" => $b->PackageFolder->__toString(),
            ));
```

Comment: I have just tried it. The array ends up with just one record. This is caused because of the variable `$var` is always the same and therefore it gets overwritten in the loop.